# What's the difference between Jhipster UAA and cloud foundry UAA

Tags: jhipster

What's the difference between Jhipster UAA and cloud foundry UAA, are they compatible with each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't describe it entirely but from http://jhipster.github.io/using-uaa/

> JHipster UAA is a user accounting and authorizing service for securing JHipster microservices using the OAuth2 authorization protocol.
>
> To clearly distinct JHipster UAA from other “UAA”s as cloudfoundrys UAA, JHipster UAA is an fully configured OAuth2 authorization server with the users and roles endpoints inside, wrapped into a usual JHipster application. This allows the developer to deeply configure every aspect of his user domain, without restricting on policies by other ready-to-use UAAs.

I'd say that JHipster UAA is simply a spring-boot app (tweaks a-la jhipster...but without the angular client-side) that uses the @EnableAuthorizationServer to make the UAA app to serve as an oauth2 authorization server--granting tokens to client apps (jhipster gateways in this case) to call resource servers and providing the public key that resource servers would use to verify tokens. JHipster UAA is predominantly a server-side app at the moment. It has the authorization server code and stores the actual user information but has no UI itself for managing those users (the UI to manage it is duplicated on each gateway app). JHipster's UAA also can't do single sign on (SSO) (unlike cloudfoundry uaa) because it doesn't expose a login endpoint in the browser needed to create the session on the authorization server to enable SSO between client (or gateway) apps.

Cloudfoundry's UAA is much more comprehensive but does much the same thing (as far as doing what oauth2 authorization servers do). As it stands right now, cloudfoundry is a more mature and flexible app but isn't integrated with jhipster out of the box...yet.

I currently still have an old public github repo that integrates jhipster with cloudfoundry uaa but jhipster has changed a lot since. https://github.com/sdoxsee/jhipster-openid-connect-microservices